# I'm blind, how can I figure out the captas on Tor sights?

Tags: onion-services

Often times when making an account there is a CAPTCHA and they don't have an audio alternative.

How can a blind person get around this as it can cause issues for a blind person wanting to speak with others about things often censored on regular social media sites such as anarchy, real occult stuff, like meeting in person and even anything far left. Facebook is often biased and doesn't allow someone to speak their mind.

Comment: how do you read what you type

Comment: Isn't there a Captcha when searching content on Stack Exchange sites? Maybe use the way you get past this Captcha on other websites? This is also bigger than just a Tor subsection of stack exchange - it can apply for other stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

Over time, web providers are catching on the the fact that the visually impaired cannot easily solve CAPTCHAs.  There are many tools that will solve the original style of CAPTCHA for you, one example is  https://captchabegone.com/ which should be able to intercept and solve a CAPTCHA on an onion site.  At the moment, tools such as this are your best bet.  All you can do is some trial and error.

Going beyond this...
If the site uses the more modern reCAPTCHA - the sort that asks you to click on squares containing cars or similar visual tests - they have an audio button which should be detected by browsers for the blind, as shown  [here](https://support.google.com/recaptcha/answer/6175971?hl=en) .  The problem is that the likes of *ChromeVox*, *JAWS*, *NVDA* or *VoiceOver* won't display onion sites.  But then, reCAPTCHAs that rely upon Google servers for authentication aren't likely to be found on onion sites.

The W3C is actively trying to produce an alternative to CAPTCHA for use by people with various impairments, [see here for current thinking](https://www.w3.org/TR/turingtest/), but again, onion sites are not being considered.

The underlying issue is that people putting up sites on Tor don't pay attention to disability legislation.  Also, of course, they are unlikely to be found and prosecuted for it.